# "I was not sure that a final decision has been made about me"

Tags: grammaticality

I've asked in an email/letter if a potential employer has already made a decision about my situation in regards to a job offer.

Which sentence  is correct?

> I was not sure that a final decision has been made on me.

> I was not sure that a final decision has been made about me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use the first sentence.  It's fine in spoken English, but in written/formal English (*especially* a job application) it should be avoided.

The second sentence is fine, put I would not recommend it either.  Instead, I would say:

> I am not sure whether a final decision has been made regarding my application.

This sounds better, matches the tenses, and get's rid of the rather vague "me."  (Just saying "me" doesn't clearly state what you are asking.)